# Multiplet select statements, each one uses CASE and return two values

Tags: mysql

i have the follwoing query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(income_adsense, income_adsense_u) AS "REV",
   CASE COALESCE(income_adsense, income_adsense_u)
       WHEN income_adsense THEN "REAL"
       WHEN income_adsense_u THEN "USER"
   END AS source
FROM revenue_report LIMIT 1;
```

which will return answer like this:

```
REV  |  source
376  |   REAL
```

now the query works fine but the problem is i want to execute this select couple of times for different entity (adsense in the example).
the best i could get is this:

```
SELECT rr.site_id, ws.website_name,
   CASE COALESCE(income_adsense, income_adsense_u) 
       WHEN income_adsense THEN "REAL"
       WHEN income_adsense_u THEN "USER"
   END AS adsense_source,
   CASE COALESCE(income_taboola, income_taboola_u)
       WHEN income_taboola THEN "REAL"
       WHEN income_taboola_u THEN "USER"
   END AS taboola_source
FROM revenue_report rr
INNER JOIN websites ws ON ws.website_id = rr.site_id
WHERE (data_date BETWEEN '2017-03-18' AND '2017-03-18')
GROUP BY site_id
LIMIT 1
```

but the problem here is i'm missing the "REV" value from the upper example. I know it doesn't exists in the second query, but this is the last working attempt. any idea how can i add the "REV" value logic to the second query?

in the second query i will get this structure of result:

```
site_id|website_name|adsense_source|taboola_source
```

but here im missing the `COALESCE` result from the first query which in the example was 376

Comment: Could you give some examples of the input data and the desired output? I'm struggling to understand what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why can't you just include it in your `SELECT` list like

```
SELECT rr.site_id, ws.website_name,
   COALESCE(income_adsense, income_adsense_u) AS "REV", //Here
   CASE COALESCE(income_adsense, income_adsense_u) 
       WHEN income_adsense THEN "REAL"
       WHEN income_adsense_u THEN "USER"
   END AS adsense_source,
   CASE COALESCE(income_gol, income_gol_u)
       WHEN income_taboola THEN "REAL"
       WHEN income_taboola_u THEN "USER"
   END AS taboola_source
FROM revenue_report rr
INNER JOIN websites ws ON ws.website_id = rr.site_id
WHERE (data_date BETWEEN '2017-03-18' AND '2017-03-18')
GROUP BY site_id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: update my question, hope it helps understand the issue with your answer.

Comment: @yarivbar, no it's still not clear enough. Why can't you add that expression to select?

Comment: adding the 2nd row in your query again before the second CASE was what i needed..thx